# Creating record with foreign key fails when using sequelize.transaction

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a simple `Message` belongs to `User`, `Message` belongs to `Chat` schema.

```js
  models.Chat.hasMany(models.Message);
  models.Message.belongsTo(models.Chat);

  models.User.hasMany(models.Message);
  models.Message.belongsTo(models.User);
```

When I create a new `Message` record (after creating both `User` and `Chat` records), the following works fine:

```js
      const message = await models.Message.create({
        UserId: user_id,
        ChatId: chat_id,
        content: content,
      });
```

however the following with an enclosing managed transaction fails:

```js
      const message = await sequelize.transaction(
        async (transaction: Transaction) => {
          // First create the message.
          const ret = await models.Message.create(
            {
              UserId: user_id,
              ChatId: chat_id,
              content: content,
            },
            { transaction }
          );
          return ret;
        }
      );
```

with the error:

```js
      {
        name: 'SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError',
        parent: error: insert or update on table "Messages" violates foreign key constraint "Messages_ChatId_fkey"
            at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/mnt/ubuntu/home/richardwu/code/topspin-apollo-backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:357:11)
            at Parser.handlePacket (/mnt/ubuntu/home/richardwu/code/topspin-apollo-backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:186:21)
            at Parser.parse (/mnt/ubuntu/home/richardwu/code/topspin-apollo-backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:101:30)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (/mnt/ubuntu/home/richardwu/code/topspin-apollo-backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:327:20)
            at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:304:12)
            at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:279:9)
            at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:218:10)
            at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:192:23) {
          length: 286,
          severity: 'ERROR',
          code: '23503',
          detail: 'Key (ChatId)=(900e18b1-1a62-45b7-bd74-3cecc8a80de8) is not present in table "Chats".',
          hint: undefined,
          position: undefined,
          internalPosition: undefined,
          internalQuery: undefined,
          where: undefined,
          schema: 'public',
          table: 'Messages',
          column: undefined,
          dataType: undefined,
          constraint: 'Messages_ChatId_fkey',
          file: 'ri_triggers.c',
          line: '2463',
          routine: 'ri_ReportViolation',
          sql: 'INSERT INTO "Messages" ("id","content","createdAt","updatedAt","ChatId","UserId") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING "id","content","createdAt","updatedAt","ChatId","UserId";',
          parameters: [
            '392749a4-267e-4e8f-b58d-93ad84004ab3',
            'hello',
            '2021-02-27 21:10:41.306 +00:00',
            '2021-02-27 21:10:41.306 +00:00',
            '900e18b1-1a62-45b7-bd74-3cecc8a80de8',
            '843095e7-0ee1-4db5-bfcf-d14d5e595019'
          ]
        },
        original: error: insert or update on table "Messages" violates foreign key constraint "Messages_ChatId_fkey"
            at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/mnt/ubuntu/home/richardwu/code/topspin-apollo-backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:357:11)
            at Parser.handlePacket (/mnt/ubuntu/home/richardwu/code/topspin-apollo-backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:186:21)
            at Parser.parse (/mnt/ubuntu/home/richardwu/code/topspin-apollo-backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:101:30)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (/mnt/ubuntu/home/richardwu/code/topspin-apollo-backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:327:20)
            at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:304:12)
            at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:279:9)
            at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:218:10)
            at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:192:23) {
          length: 286,
          severity: 'ERROR',
          code: '23503',
          detail: 'Key (ChatId)=(900e18b1-1a62-45b7-bd74-3cecc8a80de8) is not present in table "Chats".',
          hint: undefined,
          position: undefined,
          internalPosition: undefined,
          internalQuery: undefined,
          where: undefined,
          schema: 'public',
          table: 'Messages',
          column: undefined,
          dataType: undefined,
          constraint: 'Messages_ChatId_fkey',
          file: 'ri_triggers.c',
          line: '2463',
          routine: 'ri_ReportViolation',
          sql: 'INSERT INTO "Messages" ("id","content","createdAt","updatedAt","ChatId","UserId") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING "id","content","createdAt","updatedAt","ChatId","UserId";',
          parameters: [
            '392749a4-267e-4e8f-b58d-93ad84004ab3',
            'hello',
            '2021-02-27 21:10:41.306 +00:00',
            '2021-02-27 21:10:41.306 +00:00',
            '900e18b1-1a62-45b7-bd74-3cecc8a80de8',
            '843095e7-0ee1-4db5-bfcf-d14d5e595019'
          ]
        },
        sql: 'INSERT INTO "Messages" ("id","content","createdAt","updatedAt","ChatId","UserId") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING "id","content","createdAt","updatedAt","ChatId","UserId";',
        parameters: [
          '392749a4-267e-4e8f-b58d-93ad84004ab3',
          'hello',
          '2021-02-27 21:10:41.306 +00:00',
          '2021-02-27 21:10:41.306 +00:00',
          '900e18b1-1a62-45b7-bd74-3cecc8a80de8',
          '843095e7-0ee1-4db5-bfcf-d14d5e595019'
        ],
        fields: null,
        table: 'Messages',
        value: undefined,
        index: 'Messages_ChatId_fkey',
        reltype: undefined
      }
```

I did for sure verify that the Chat with the provided ID does exist by querying `models.Chat.findAll` before the transaction as well as before the `await models.Message.create` inside the transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this had to do with the `sequelize` instance I was using in my tests vs what's actually used in my Express app.

I was importing the global `sequelize` instance that I initialize for my Express app, but was using a different `sequelize` instance for my tests.